# EF Code First Insert Objects with One to Many gives exception."Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0)."

Tags: asp.net, linq, exception, ef-code-first, one-to-many

I am using POCO classes with EF Code First.

I have a class Ball as:

```
public class Ball
{
    [Key]
    public int BallId { get; set; }

    public Box Container { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool IsCounted{get; set;}
}
```

and a class Box as:

```
public class Box
{
    [Key]
    public int BoxId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Ball> Balls { get; set; }

}
```

I have a list of already created Balls, using which I wish to create a new Box!
When the box is created:

1. Every ball should have its IsCounted property true
2. The box.Balls reference should point to the existing objects
3. The ball.Container should point to the new Box!

   ```
   public void CreateBox(string Description, ICollection<Ball> givenBalls)
   {
       using (var c = new BoxEntryModel())
       {
           Box entry = new Box();
           if (c.Boxes.Count().Equals(0))
               entry.BoxId = 1;
           else 
               entry.BoxId = c.Boxes.Max<Box>(b => b.BoxId) + 1;
           entry.Description = Description;
           entry.Balls = givenBalls;                
           try
           {
               foreach (Ball ball in givenBalls)
               {
                   c.Balls.Attach(ball);
                   ball.IsCounted = true;
                   ball.Container = entry;
               }
               c.Boxes.Add(entry);
               c.SaveChanges();
           }
   }
   ```

   This piece of code, gives me an exception:

Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.OptimisticConcurrencyException: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.

**Also, if i comment the line *c.Balls.Attach(expense);* the code works, but it creates new rows for each Ball that I am trying to add to the box.**

Please help me save the entities as per the relations.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @manishKungwani, is givenBalls already on the database or are you creating them in your code?

Comment: Hi, where do you define expense in this code?

Comment: Expense is defined in the same DataContext and the givenBalls is already in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code that you've put here it seems that you don't actually have the FK between Balls and Box properly set up in EF. EF might be confused as to why you're attaching the Balls when there's nothing that's being edited (at least according to EF, that is). Try setting up the following in your Box code:

```
public class Ball
{
    [Key]
    public int BallId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Container")]
    public int BoxID { get; set; }

    public Box Container { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool IsCounted{get; set;}
}
```

If that doesn't work, Check the EntityState for each of the balls in givenBalls (`c.Entry(ball).State`), and see if they've become detached.

Let me know how that works.